# auto-suggest keyboard event not working on keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, keyboard-events

I am creating auto-suggest from scratch. I am using jquery-ajax function to get the data from server. I am doing filtering data on keyup event for auto suggestion.

Now after filtering I want to navigate the list items using keyboard's arrow keys but the problem is every time I am pressing the arrow key the list is being refreshed on keyup event which clears the selection happened through arrow key.

I track trace my code and I came to know this reason.
Here is my code :

```
var $listItems = $('li.suggestion-item');
   var key = event.keyCode,$current,
   $selected = $listItems.filter('.selected');
   if ( key != 40 && key != 38 ) { return key; }
   $listItems.removeClass('selected');
   switch(key){    
     case 40: // Down key
       if (! $selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child')) {
            $current = $listItems.eq(0).addClass('selected');
       }
       else {
            $current = $selected.removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected');
       }
           break;
       case 38: // Up key
       if ( $selected.length ===1 || $selected.is(':first-child') ) {
            $current = $listItems.last();
       }
       else {
          $current = $selected.prev();
       }
       break;
       case 13:
            $('.suggestion-item, .error').hide();
            break;      
    }
    } else {
          $('#validline').removeClass('true');
          $('.suggestion-item, .error').hide();      
     }
 }
```

can anybody suggest me the solution of this problem?

Comment: Just skip the ajax call while key code is 38 or 40

Comment: @SurendarKannan: can you tell me how to skip ? Sorry for it but I am novice for ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

```
$("#inputField").keyup(function(){
    if(keycode!=38 || keycode!=40){
        //proceed to fetch suggestion...
    }else{
        //proceed navigation..
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually I am using canjs and I am doing event handling using can.controller.
But I got it how to do that.
Anyways thanx for the answer.